# Excel js add-in access outlook/create email

Tags: excel, office-js

The last question I can find is from 2018. I see in the documentation that there is an example of `Office.context.mailbox.item`. On my personal computer it doesn't exist in excel, but would this work in AD domain computers to send email from excel in a local/on-prem-only office installation?

Comment: Hello. Unfortunately there is no mailbox space in Excel. This api is not supposed to work at Ms Excel. Can you please clarify a bit on what exactly you're looking for?

Comment: Currently we have VBA applications we'd like to migrate that send mass emails with `CreateObject("Outlook.Application")` and pulling columns from the spreadsheet to get the addresses, names, and other information. 
I don't know if `js` addins can communicate with other tabs by communicating with `LocalStorage` events; that might be a solution.

Comment: Currently the LocalStorage you requested, is not official supported by Excel OfficeJS. We track Office Add-in feature requests on our [UserVoice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.